# Javascript RegEx String with Variable

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have the following RegEx that works:

```
var expression = /s\[0\]\[children\]\[.*?\]\[/g;
var replace_string = "s[" + count + "][children][" + subCount + "]";
$input.attr('name', $input.attr('name').replace(expression, replace_string));
```

Now I am wanting to replace the 0 in the above regex with a variable, "count". I have read up that it needs to be turned into a string, which I have done:

```
var expression = "/s\\[" + count + "\\]\\[children\\]\\[.*?\\]/g";
```

But that doesn't want to work for some reason, what am I doing wrong?

Cheers

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: nucleo_isotope_gallery_filters[0][children][0][preset_referrer]
nucleo_isotope_gallery_filters[0][children][1][preset_referrer]
nucleo_isotope_gallery_filters[0][children][2][preset_referrer]
etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `RegExp` constructor whenever you want to call a variable from regex.

```
var expression = new RegExp("s\\[" + count + "\\]\\[children\\]\\[.*?\\]", "g");
```